# Why do changes to /etc/passwd not take effect?

Tags: ssh, login

I've edited `/etc/passwd` by running `usermod -s` to change my shell. (`chsh` doesn't work, because it prompts for a password; we SSH in using keys.)

When I disconnect, and reconnect, the change doesn't take effect. I've restarted `sshd` too, and still nothing.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to live with that `chsh` problem. At least in the Linux version the password prompting is configurable. If you ask a separate question and mention your OS version you might get it fixed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use `ControlMaster`, and I wasn't actually disconnecting.

`ControlMaster` is an SSH configuration option that keeps connections open for a certain time, and can multiplex SSH sessions over the same connection (which avoids key exchanges, which are slow). However, if you ^D from a shell, and then re-run `ssh`, *you've not killed the original connection*.

Restarting `sshd` only restarts the listening process: any in-progress session remain alive, so that doesn't restart the connection either.

Apparently launching a new shell doesn't re-check `/etc/passwd` for changes.

Solution was just to kill the connection: `ssh <hostname> -O exit`, and log in again.